# Kafka on EC2 instance for integration testing

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I'm trying to set up some integration tests for part of our project that makes use of Kafka. I've chosen to use the [spotify/kafka](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/spotify/kafka/dockerfile/) docker image which contains both kafka and Zookeeper. 
I can run my tests (and they pass!) on a local machine if I run the kafka container as described at that project site. When I try to run it on my ec2 build server, however, the container dies. The final fatal error is "**INFO gave up: kafka entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly**".

My suspicion is that it doesn't like the address passed in. I've tried using both the public and the private ip address that ec2 provides, but the results are the same either way, just as with localhost.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If it helps anyone else, I just had this issue and it was because there was not enough memory in my t1.micro to run kafka. You can fix this by passing `--env KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx256M -Xms128M"` to the docker run command.

Comment: @RossDeane your solution worked for me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It magically works now even though I'm still doing exactly what I was doing before. However, in order to help others who might come along, I will post what I did to get it to work.

I created the following batch file and have jenkins run this as a build step.

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! docker inspect -f 1 test_kafka &>/dev/null
then docker run -d --name test_kafka -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=localhost --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 spotify/kafka
fi
```

even though the localhost resolves to the private ip address, it seems to take it now. The if block is just to test if the container already exists and reuse it otherwise.